# How to query DynamoDb realtime from reporting tool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, tableau-api, amazon-dynamodb-streams

How to query DynamoDb real time from reporting tool like Tableau ? I know there are third party jdbc drivers which are not free. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: [Connect to DynamoDB as an ODBC Data Source](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/dynamodb-odbc-tableau.rst)